# After Effects: How to make 3D path

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to make a 3D path that will be used as motion path for a object as well as base for `Trim Paths`.

In other words, I would like to create something like Nyan Cat. I am going to use a path to animate movement of a 'cat' and to use same path to animate 'rainbow' by using `Trim Paths`. A 'cat' must move through 3D space eventually. Not sure if I chosen right direction so I would appreciate any tips about best practices for that kind of tasks.

However I would really love to learn how to create 3D paths to use them as trajectory for a camera, for example.

What I tried:

To create a circle -> make it 3D ->change its orientation -> `convert to Bezier Path`-ctrl+c. And then if I try to paste the copied path into an object `position` it get inserted as a 2D path. I could create 3D motion path for a camera manually using a `Pen tool`, however I would like a path to be a right circle.

Sorry if my question seems to be stupid, I am a really new. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a path with the `Pen Tool` first, copy the property `path` under:

> Contents > Shape 1 > Path > `Path`

Create a `NULL object` and paste the value you just copied to its `position` property.

You now have a NULL that follows your 2D path.

---

To enable the *Z-axis* of the NULL position, toggle the `3D Layer setting`.

Click on the NULL position property and then get into the `Graph Editor`, in the bottom bar click the icon `Separate Dimensions`, this way you now have the 3 axis as separate properties.

---

You can see the `Z Position` is set at 0 without keyframes, despite the other 2 axis, play now with the `Z Position` and add keyframes as wished to give a 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension to your previously created 2D path.

Comment: You can link a camera to the NULL object.